# What is the following function returning ?

Tags: c++, c, return, output, generic-programming

```
int fn(unsigned int x)
{
int count = 0 ;
for(; x!=0; x&=(x-1))
    count ++;
return count;
}
```

I tried it out in the complier but couldn't figure out what is happening. I think it's something to do with the number of bits the in `x`, but what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I explain what you have done :)

As per your code , following will happen if x = 5

1) In first iteration of loop,

```
  a) condition check : .... 0101(X) ! = 0 ,
  b) body : count will be 1 ;
  c) increment part : .... 0101 &= .... 0100 => .... 0100
```

2) In second Itearation

```
a) condition check : .... 0100(X) ! = 0 ,
  b) body : count will be 2 ;
  c) increment part : .... 0100 &= .... 0011 => .... 0000
```

The count is equal to 2 which is number of bits set in X(5)

Answer (score 9):

It's a [bit trick](http://www.ugcs.caltech.edu/~wnoise/base2.html).  :)

You're returning the number of bits set to `1`.